# How to find the entire device's CPU consumption from my iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, ios, system

I'm trying to find the API's to get the CPU consumption of the entire device. Currently, I'm able to find out CPU consumed by my Application. But I'm not gettig any help for the device's CPU consumption. Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Apple does not provides such API's but I dont know if you can use below github code.

Though this code does not have what you want but may it help you. Go through below github link:

https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension

Comment: Thanks DShah... tht helped... I got wat i wanted.